# Android: "waiting for debugger" hang-up

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to resolve “Waiting for Debugger” message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375375/how-to-resolve-waiting-for-debugger-message)

This might be helpfull for the one or the other:
If the debugger doesn't attach (hang-up of the screen "waiting for debugger), then you probably use the phone device and the emulator at the same time.

Just unplug the phone or close the emulator and everything's fine again.

Comment: Sometime I have this situation even with unplugged device.

Comment: This is a tip, a question asked and answered. I think there is a place on StackExchange for this, but perhaps the developers should update the site to support things like this.

Comment: I've experienced the corollary of this issue. Again, might help someone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814986/android-handlerthread-stops-working-when-device-unplugged-from-usb-cable