# Can't disable DDMS debug once enabled

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-debug

This issue is driving me nuts...I'm using eclipse Juno with latest SDK 21.1

My app runs regularly, I can easily start it from eclipse with *Run as...* command. But, from the first time I run it in debug mode, I can't disable it in any way. Even when I disconnect USB cable and after having killed the app, when I launch it again it keeps asking for debugger (*Application xxx is waiting for the debugger to attach*). This is very annoying, since I can't use the app and only found solution is to [restart the phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375375/how-to-resolve-waiting-for-debugger-message). Restarting both ADB and Eclipse didn't work, disable/enable device's debug mode and *force-close* the app are useless too.

My process is shown under DDMS "devices" panel, but **the button used to enable debug** (the green bug) **isn't a toggle one** (like *update heap* button)

I don't know if it's a device issue (I'm using CM10.1 on Nexus S) or eclipse/DDMS one, but I noticed it since android 4.2 update on my Nexus 7, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I want to disconnect the DDMS i use this button:

[image: disconnect]

It is located next to the "step over" and "step into" buttons.