# What ADB code triggers (or causes) an android application to say "Waiting for debugger to attach" I am just curious

Tags: android, adb

I like having fun with certain programming code lines so here I am and would like to know which Android debug code triggers an application or android system to display a dialogue box with the information saying "Application waiting for debugger to attach", thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Debugger has few stuff at kernel level. normally debugger is used by only developers to debug the application (user've nothing to do with this.) we can manually / automatically attach the debugger. additionally, it was a bug earlier. for info about steps:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35637464/10705803