# Application waiting for debugger to attach in Android

Tags: android, device

I have a really weird problem, which is that when I run my app in Android Studio by using Android Emulator has no problem and it will show what I designed.

But when I choose "Run by My Device (Samsung Note 3, Android version 5.0)" it says "Application Waiting for debugger to attach android".

That is so weird! In android emulator is ok, but in my device(phone) has error ? I try everything I find in Stack Overflow, but it doesn't work.

Comment: have you enabled USB debuggin in your device? http://www.buzznet.com/2013/10/enable-usb-debugging-android-samsung/

Comment: This is not an issue, just run the app without debug

Comment: @iguarna Yes, i select -> Developer Options-> USB debugging "true" but it doesn't work

Comment: @ViktorYakunin Hi, sorry i don't understand your mean T__T 
so i should build apk in my phone and install ? sorry T_T

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375375/how-to-resolve-waiting-for-debugger-message

Comment: i think maybe my Android Version is not match to my device?

Comment: @iguarna thanks a lot, i try again TT

Comment: @iguarna sorry, i tried it again but it didn't work :(  
Then i just  open another empty project and run the new project again, it run successfully and show Hello World in my phone , that mean is my project has errors ?