# Annoyance debugging app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

When trying to debug an app in android studio when I press the debug button it builds and installs the app but it displays 'waiting for debugger' on phone/tablet I'm trying to debug my app on, I have to connect the debugger through studio using the 'attach debugger to app' button rather than just automatically attaching the debugger and running. I know it sounds like a small problem but when you are doing this a lot it takes a lot of your time that could be spent debugging the app or writing feature code!

Running Android Studio 2.3 Beta 3 and Java 8

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375375/how-to-resolve-waiting-for-debugger-message

Comment: This is not a new problem with the app, it has worked perfectly fine for at least three years without having this happen, so the solution posted in the post you say is a duplicate does not work. And one of the solutions in your 'duplicate question' is the exact workaround I don't want to have to do everytime

Comment: and none of the accepted answers from the question you reference solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the built in emulator that Android Studio comes with, 
[Visual Studio's stand alone Android Emulator](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/)

That way you can debug your code on your development device without messing with adb

Comment: I definitely dont plan on changing my IDE to Visual Studio, will this work with andorid studio as they each get updated by different sets of developers?

Comment: @SBC The visual studio emulator is stand alone, and hooks right up to Android Studio with little effort.